# jQuery tooltip appears in the wrong place on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm using jQuery UI `position()` to position a custom tooltip. The problem I have is that the tooltip always appears in the same place (at the top of the table), when I want it appear when an anchor is hovered (inside a table row).

The code looks like this:

```
$('.sales-dashboard td a').on('hover', function() {    
    $('#tooltip')
        .insertAfter($(this))
        .toggleClass('is-hidden')
        .position({ 
            my: "left center", 
            at: "right center", 
            of: ".sales-dashboard td a" 
        });
});
```

A table row looks like this (the tooltip div is being inserted after the closing tag of the anchor);

```
<tr class="even">
    <td><a href="#">123</a></td>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>Valid</td>
    <td>Device is active</td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the tooltip to appear next to the anchor that is hovered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the positioning of the tooltip by passing `this` to the **of** in the position method and adding an offset;

```
$('.sales-dashboard td a').on('hover', function () {

    $('#tooltip').insertAfter($(this)).toggleClass('is-hidden')
    .position({ my: "left center", at: "right center", of: $(this), offset: "20 0" });
});
```